# Repair apparently damaged pdf and reduce file size

Tags: linux, pdf, compression, pdftk

I have a PDF file (4.6MB) which was made by combining 6 different PDFs (containing both text and bitmap graphics) using `pdftk` in Ubuntu 12.04. I wish to compress this file to something close to 2MB without affecting its quality.

I have tried pdftk's "compress" option (couldn't compress it to 2 MB), also tried converting it to ps first and than back to pdf, it gives the following warning:

> ****Warning: considering '0000000000 XXXXX n' as a free entry.

and then hangs. `qpdf` also failed saying that the file is damaged.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Are the graphics vector or bitmap? You might get some compression wins if you increase the bitmap lossiness - though I would imagine it would be better to do this at generation time, rather than reprocessing the file.

Comment: Ooh, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14429/pdftex-reduce-pdf-size-reduce-image-quality) looks like it will help.

Comment: I couldn't compress the graphics (it's bitmap by the way) in the pdf files since I do not have the source files for all the pdfs.

Comment: Just a bit of advice for your next question. Give detail (e.g. that your graphics are bitmaps) and what you've tried (e.g. Multivalent). It'll save time for everyone!

Comment: Also: any luck with Ghostscript?

Comment: No with gs also I couldn't achieve such high compression ratio. I need to compress a file from 4.6 MB to about 2 MB.

Comment: For those who might be looking for something like this: **Both the following answers are correct**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has this pdf file reserved infos? If it has no confidential data it would be interesting to see

anyway many times where qpdf fails, **Multivalent** works

you can try to use its **Compress tool** (it also attempts to repair pdf file)

**Multivalent**

- https://rg.to/file/c6bd7f31bf8885bcaa69b50ffab7e355/Multivalent20060102.jar.html
  (latest free version with tools included, current has no tools in itself)

> java -cp path....to/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Compress file.pdf

Comment: Tried using Multivalent but it couldn't compress my file to more than 4.1 MB. Though it suggests that:

**additional compression may be possible with:
  -compact -jpeg -nopagepiece**

And I have no idea how to implement it. I tried as follows but failed.
_java -compact ./Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Compress file.pdf_

Comment: right syntax is (assuming, for instance, you downloaded **Multivalent.jar** in /root: `java -cp /root/Multivalent.jar tool.pdf.Compress -jpeg -nopagepiece file.pdf`

Comment: Ya now it works but still could achieve the required file size. Now it's compressed to 4.0 MB. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: beyond a certain limit, with pdf containing **raster images**, it is impossible to achieve an high compression ratio without sacrificing the quality. You must decide if you need quality or prefer degrade images for pdf intended **NOT FOR PRINT** but only to view on screen. A pdf with low-res images is useless, in my opinion, you need in any case an high quality backup copy to not lose ability to print file in good quality if necessary. if images inside pdf can tolerate **Black and White** binarization, I can modify answer to add instruction to use jbig2enc

Answer (score 6):

What result does Ghostscript give you? Try this command:

```
gs \
  -o output.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen \
   input.pdf
```

Comment: No couldn't achieve required compression ratio.

Comment: @Harsh Purwar: So how much **DID** this Ghostscript command reduce the file size?!?

Comment: @Harsh Purwar: Without being able to have a look at + analyze the file in question, it is not possible to give better advice. It may simply be impossible to further reduce the file size.

Comment: Well your gs command compressed it to about 4.0 MB. And yes now I also think that it might be impossible to compress it further without affecting the quality. Thanks any ways.

Comment: @HarshPurwar - I recommend that you generally answer in more detail, and using answers such as this as _starting points_ for more research. So, does GS offer options to alter the compression ratio? Can you re-encode bitmaps with greater lossiness etc? Read the manual, rather than just saying that "it didn't work" `:)`

Comment: @halfer: Yes I shall keep that in mind and **no I can not re-encode the bitmaps** since I do not have the source files as well as the included graphics. _I will post a solution if I find it in the man page of GS._ Thanks.

Comment: @HarshPurwar: gs can downsample included bitmaps when writing pdf. Check the manuals.

Comment: @HarshPurwar - I should have been more specific - when I said _re-encode the bitmaps_, I meant through GS, rather than re-creating the PDF from source, as per Martin's comment.

Comment: Right now it's 40 minutes before my PhD defense and my committee starts telling me they can't open the slides I sent them. This command saved everything. Thanks!

Comment: @rcompton: I hope your PhD defense was not *as* 'tight' as your PDF slides were...  :-)

Answer (score 4):

This works for me to repair the damaged PDF

```
sudo apt-get install mupdf-tools
```

```
mutool clean input.pdf output.pdf
```

Comment: This fixed it for me too where pdftk failed! thanks for the nice share!